# How I do draw a straight line in r with coefficients straight

Tags: r, plot, line

I have two sequence, which have three variable A, B and C
Ax+By+C=0 this is General straight pattern and I want to draw this straight line in r
Example
p1=c(2,3,4)

we have 2x+3y+4=0
so straight directional pattern looks like this
(2x+4)/(-3)=y

How do i draw this straight line in R

In advance thank you for help me

Comment: Did you try abline() ? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html

Comment: yes, i tried, but i think this plot is wrong this is a image a plot here: http://imgur.com/a/tskZ9

Comment: `abline(-4/3, -2/3)`  Or more generally, `abline(-C/B, -A/B)`